# Change content automatically when modifying JSON file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I would like to know if it is possible to update the content automatically without having to reload the webpage manually when changing the values in the JSON file. Do I need to use jQuery instead of plain javascript to achieve this?

I have already used onreadystatechange to load the JSON file using XMLHttpRequest.

if it is possible, how can I achieve this?

JavaScript

```
var carsContainer = document.getElementById('carsGrid');

carsContainer.addEventListener("load", loadJSON());

function loadJSON()
{
    //sent request
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //let jsonFile = "./cars.json";
     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //convert json file to java object
        console.log(request.readyState);
        if(request.status == 200)
        {
            if(request.readyState == 4)
            {
                try {
                     const jsonDataObj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    renderHtml(jsonDataObj.cars);
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    console.warn("Failed to parse JSON file, please check for syntax errors.");
                }
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("Unable to load JSON file");
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", "./cars.json", true);
    request.send();
}

function renderHtml(carsData)
{
    var htmlString = "<div class='grid-container'>\n";
    
    for(var i = 0; i< carsData.length; i++)
    {
        //convert java object to string for the purpose of adding it to cart using PHP
        const carDataStr = JSON.stringify(carsData[i]);
        
        //console.log(carsData[i].brand + "\n");
        htmlString += "<div class='grid-item'> \n";
        //insert images based on car model name from JSON
        htmlString += "<img width='245' height='160' src='./images/"+ carsData[i].model + ".jpg'/> \n";
        //insert Title of the cars
        htmlString += "<h3>"+carsData[i].brand+"-"+carsData[i].model + "-" + carsData[i].year+"</h3> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Category: </b>"+carsData[i].category +"</p> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Mileage: </b>"+carsData[i].mileage +"</p> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Fuel: </b>"+carsData[i].fuel +"</p> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Seats: </b>"+carsData[i].seats +"</p> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Price: </b>$"+carsData[i].price +"</p> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Availability: </b>"+carsData[i].availability +"</p> \n";
        htmlString += "<p><b>Description: </b>"+carsData[i].description +"</p> \n";
        //htmlString += "<form id='carForm"+formCounter+"' action='shoppingCart.php' method='get' onsubmit='return isAvaliable(carsData[i].availability)'> \n ";
       
        if(carsData[i].availability == false)
        {
            htmlString += "<div class='tooltip'>";
            htmlString += "<a href='#' disabled><button  disabled class='disabled-button'>Add to Cart</button></a>";
            htmlString += "<span class='tooltiptext'>Sorry, this car is not available to rent, please try another car.</span>";
            htmlString += "</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            htmlString +=  "<a  href='shoppingCart.php?method=add&jsonString="+carDataStr+"'><button class='green-button button'>Add to Cart</button></a>";
        
        }
        htmlString += "</div> \n";
        //console.log(carDataStr + "\n");
        //formCounter++;
    }
    
    htmlString += "</div> \n";
    
    carsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", htmlString);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hertz UTS Car Rental Cent4erf</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header-placeholder"><h1 class="text-center">Car Rentel Center</h1></div>
            <div class='right-button-header'><a href="./shoppingCart.php"><button class="white-button button">Reservation</button></a></div>
        </header>
            <div class="center">
              <div id="carsGrid">
                      
              </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `carsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", htmlString);` will add your html to your container element. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: I have changed it to inner HTML, however, I am still able to see the output but when I change values on the JSON file and save it, I have to refresh the page manually, the question is: how can I get the values to update automatically on the index page after changing values on the JSON file?

Comment: You are rendering the html by processing your JSON result, if you need to change anything in your JSON and then need to show these changes in your HTML, you would need to render the HTML after updating your JSON.

Comment: is there an event listener specifically for that? where it listens to changes on the JSON file?